# fbox without vspace

Tags: parbox, vspace, fbox

I am going to give a definition of a problem as follows.

```
\newcommand{\defproblem}[3]{
    \vspace{4mm}
    \noindent\fbox{
        \parbox{0.98\textwidth}{
             #1 \\
             \textbf{Input}: #2 \\
             \textbf{Output}: #3
         }
    }
    \vspace{4mm}
}
```

This is an example of using the command.
[image]

However, some journals require that commands such as \vspace should not be used as much as possible.

If I just remove the \vspace directly,
it looks like
[image]
we can see that there is no space (of height 4mm) before or behind the fbox.

Is there a way to obtain the same effect without using \vspace?

Is it possible to put the fbox in another box (or minipage) and set the parameters of the box (or minipage)?

Comment: At least, we need to know which command is allowed?

Comment: @Tom As far as I know,  \textheight, \vspace, baselinestretch are not allowed. I think the commands that only work for various boxes or minipage are acceptable.

Comment: Are you trying to typesetting an algorithm?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I am afraid not, I need to first give the definition of the problem and solve this problem in the rest of my paper, many papers in the field define a problem by using this format.

Comment: Maybe they just want to cram as much text as possible onto each page.  It is not `\vspace` per se but the total space used that matters.  If you use \vfill instead the added space will always be less that \baselineskip or whatever is wasted at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\begin{trivlist}\item[] ... \end{trivlist}`, a vertical separation of `\topsep [+ \parskip]` is added both before and after the problem definition. See https://latexref.xyz/trivlist.html and https://latexref.xyz/list.html for more info.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\defproblem}[3]{%
    \begin{trivlist}\item[]
    \fbox{%
        \parbox{0.98\textwidth}{%
             #1 \\
             \textbf{Input}: #2 \\
             \textbf{Output}: #3
         }%
    }%
    \end{trivlist}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\defproblem{a}{b}{c}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks great. If I understand correctly, the height of the space follows the setting of the whole document, right?

Comment: Yes. Inserting vertical space while avoiding normal commands being detected is a trick that I don't recommend.

Comment: I agree. I will temporarily adopt your method in my document. Thanks again.

Comment: You can use `\trivlist` and `\endtrivlist` when defining an environment; it’s wrong to use them in this context.

Comment: @egreg My bad and thank you. Changed to env form.

Answer (score 4):

They don't want people to use `\vspace` inside the document, but for structure it's certainly necessary and cannot be banned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\defproblem}[3]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{
      #1 \\
      \textbf{Input}: #2 \\
      \textbf{Output}: #3
    }%
  }%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\defproblem{x}{y}{z}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

I changed it into `\addvspace`, not only because it is not `\vspace`, but because it cooperates with other `\addvspace` commands next to it and use just the highest value.

Note also that I added some `%` at the end of lines, but mainly changed the width of the `\parbox` to the right value and not some random percentage of the textwidth that just seems to be correct.

[image]